# Need help to understand the error message

Tags: c++, constructor, tree, hierarchical

Compiling the code I got the following errors

code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class a     {
protected: int a=5;
    public:
    a(){cout<<"a c"<<endl;}
    };
class b {
protected: int b=6;
    public:
b(){cout<<"b c"<<endl;}
    };

class d :protected a,protected b
{
    public:
    void display()
    {cout<<a<<b<<endl;}
    d(){cout<<"d c"<<endl;}
};

int main()
{d m;
    m.display();return 0;}
```

errors:

```
/root/newtest/main.cpp|4|error: field ‘int a::a’ with same name as class [-fpermissive]|
/root/newtest/main.cpp|9|error: field ‘int b::b’ with same name as class [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Why am I getting these errors?

I have just defined constructor within `class a` and `class b`.

Comment: You called your `class` and your member `int` the same thing. That's what the error says: _error: field ‘int a::a’ with same name as class_

Comment: Can you format your code to be readable please? Sane indentation and spacing are a must.

Answer (score 3):

Your member variable and your **constructor** conflict. The C++ standard doesn't allow it:

> [[class.mem]/19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#19)
>
> In addition, if class T has a user-declared constructor, every
>   non-static data member of class T shall have a name different from T.

[Removing the constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8993f69680bfdbb), or renaming the variable will make it build just fine. The member of `class a` is allowed to be named `a`, and [it will hide the injected class name](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.hiding#2). But I hope you see how it's problematic once you need to start adding constructors, because what is `a::a` referring to, in an out of class definition? Not pleasant to parse at all.

Comment: Are you sure about removing the constructor?

Comment: @Yola - Yes, I'm sure. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.hiding#2

Comment: Formulation is a bit dubious for me, and VS doesn't accept this code. I know it is not so conformal, but still..

Comment: @Yola - There's nothing dubious. `[class.mem]` is where all the naming restrictions are given. There is no restriction unless there's a c'tor. Meaning we need to refer to the name scoping rules. And the paragraph I linked to is quite clear. A data member can hide the class name in any scope it appears (and that includes class scope).

Comment: @Yola - If you are still suspicious. Consider that C allows members to be named with the same identifier as the structure tag. This is a compatibility feature (unless there's a c'tor, in which case there's no point to discuss compatibility with C).

Comment: You are referring to [basic.scope.hiding], but [basic.lookup] tells that *injected-class-name* for the purpose of hiding is also considered to be a member.

Comment: @Yola - The injected class name is specified in the section describing **qualified lookup**. There is no qualified lookup in the OP. It's injected *for the purpose* of qualified name lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Name of member variable `int a` conflicts with *injected-class-name* which is also `a`.

> #### 12 Classes [[class]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name)
>
> A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the class-name is seen. The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name. For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name.
>
> #### 6.4 Name lookup [[basic.lookup]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup)
>
> The **injected-class-name of a class** (Clause 12) **is also considered to be a member of that class for the purposes of name hiding and lookup**.

As an option you can use different names for member variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: This is surprising to me that the issue can't be solved; i.e. we have to use different names.